# Import non Standard R packages lme4 into Python

Tags: python, r, lme4

According to documentation http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_oop.html it shows how to import R packages that is not standard in python. To my luck they do the example I need which is lme4

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface



stats = importr('stats')
base = importr('base')
lme4 = importr('lme4')
getmethod = ro.baseenv.get("getMethod")
StrVector = ro.StrVector
```

No matter what I did I got the error

```
RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'lme4'
```

I'm in windows environment and I know that this package is installed under
"C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"  not the standard "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library"

Please any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the error message is coming from the R kernel (`RRuntimeError`). This suggests that the R kernel can't find the package `lme4`. I think you have two options here:

- Launch the R kernel and install `lme4` there (`install.packages('lme4')`)
- IF you used pip/conda to install rpy2, it should have also installed R in your environment (you can confirm via `pip freeze` or `conda list`). In this case, you can use pip/conda to install lme4 via the package `r-lme` (`conda install r-lme`)

Comment: I used `conda install -c conda-forge r-lme4`